# Examples of Lattices in $\operatorname{Isom}(H^n)$ for all $n \geq 2$?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, lattices-in-lie-groups

I just had an exam today where I was asked to give an example of a lattice in $\operatorname{Isom}(H^n)$ for all $n \geq 2$, and with bonus points if I could give cocompact and noncocompact examples.

I wrote down that a group $\Gamma$ generated by reflections in a Coxeter polyhedron $P \subset H^n$ was examples of such a lattice for any $n$. Moreover, I said that if $P$ had an ideal vertex, the group acted noncocompactly, and if it had no ideal vertices, the group acted cocompactly (since $H^n / \Gamma$ is isometric to $P$).

In perusing our old class notes, however, I came across the following two results:

**Theorem (Vinberg)** There do not exist compact Coxeter polyhedra in $H^n$ for $n \geq 30$.

**Theorem (Prokhorov-Kovanskij)** There do not exist finite-volume Coxeter polyhedra in $H^n$ when $n \geq 996$.

So unless there's a subtlety I'm missing, it seems that my first answer is wrong by the second theorem, and my second answer is doubly-wrong by the first and second theorems.

I can't seem to find the answer in the course notes, and Google isn't helping much either. Is there some obvious description of a lattice in $\operatorname{Isom}(H^n)$ for any $n \geq 2$? Thanks.

Comment: Related question: Do there exist compact, constant curvature - 1 Riemannian $n$-manifolds $X$ with finite or compact groups of isometries, for $n \geq 2$? Because in that case I *think* the deck transformations of the corresponding cover $H^n \to X$ would give a (cocompact) lattice. But this is just a guess.

Comment: Interesting idea. Certainly such surfaces do not exist if they can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (it's a standard differential geometry proof to show that there must exist a point for which the sectional curvature is strictly positive). This MathOverflow post suggests that it is possible that one can create such manifolds, but it's certainly not something I would have come up with during an exam: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32597/compact-surfaces-of-negative-curvature

Comment: The question of embedding is kind of a red herring, I think. I am thinking of the theorem classifying constant curvature -1 Riemannian manifolds by their universal cover. I think it is a fact (which is not obvious to me) that constant curvature negative one surfaces have only finitely many isometries. I don't know about the higher dimensional story.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "obvious", but see Section 6.4 of [Dave Witte's book](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0106063.pdf).